# How Can I Add Value to a Field in Mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

I'm working on telegram bot that calculates daily expenses. I want to create a command that can add value to one field. The problem is, there are more than one field existing. Code below only works if there is only one row inside $inc(or if I add value to both of them, but I got to add one value). How can I add value to "house" OR "clothing", but not both

```
router.post('/addExpense', function(req, res){
    Expense.update({
        $inc: {
            house: req.body.house,
            clothing: req.body.clothing
        }
     },
     function(err, expense){
        if(err)
          return res.status(500).send("Problem adding data to db");
        res.status(200).send(expense);
     });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one way of doing this is you can check it outside of update query for not null characteristics. some way like this.

```
router.post('/addExpense', function(req, res) {
    if (req.body.house) {
        Expense.update({
                $inc: {
                    house: req.body.house,
                    //   clothing: req.body.clothing
                }
            },
            function(err, expense) {
                if (err)
                    return res.status(500).send("Problem adding data to db");
                res.status(200).send(expense);
            });

    } else {
        Expense.update({
                $inc: {
                    // house: req.body.house,
                    clothing: req.body.clothing
                }
            },
            function(err, expense) {
                if (err)
                    return res.status(500).send("Problem adding data to db");
                res.status(200).send(expense);
            });
    }
});
```

Comment: That helped a lot. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use **$set** to update the other field and **$inc** for which you wish to increment. something like this..

```
Expense.update({},{
    $inc:{ status1:1 },
    $set:{ status2:1 }
    })
```

here you have to left the first **{}** blank because this is for the *selection* criteria. add any if you have any selection criteria.
you have to write the update query in the second **{}**, here **status1** is the field you want to *increment by 1* and **status2** is the field you want to just update. here status2 value will be set to 1. you can set it to any other value according to your wish, just replace that 1 with your value.

Comment: What if I have 5 items? I want to modify only one and remain left untouched

Comment: those which you want to be left untouched then what is the need for them to be included in the update query, just don't write them in the update query

Comment: Oh, sorry, I didn't clarify that I don't know which one I'm going to increment. It depends on the query that user is going to enter

Comment: so if you want to check for the not NULL field then you can do it outside of this update query and write the update query accordingly. because writing that query in mongo would be a lot complex.